# How to remove unwanted whitespace below nav?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to remove the whitespace below this Bootstrap 3 navbar. I have tried setting margin-bottom to zero for the nav, and I have tried to do vertical-align: middle to both divs.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
<a href="#">Home</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a `margin-bottom` is the right way to go about it, you just need to increase the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of your css selector *if your css is declared before your bootstrap link*. One way to increase your selector specificity is by using `nav.navbar` as your selector.

See working example below:

```css
nav.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
</div>
```

Comment: no need it if we place the CSS after the bootstrap one ... the snippet add the CSS before

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: @phuck no worries!!